# g++-4.8 C++ stdlib dylib

Tags: c++, macos, g++, homebrew

I compiled a "Hello world" C++ file with gcc48 (installed via homebrew) and when i check the dynamic libraries linked i see:

otool -L Test

```
Test:
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.18.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

However if i compile this with an apple provided gcc,g++ i get:

```
Test:
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

How can i get g++-4.8 to link/compile with the apple provided .dylib?

EDIT: Would i just be able to distribute the program with /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib and use install_name_tool to change the path for that?

Comment: Apple's `gcc` had actually been LLVM with GCC frontend for some time; and in Xcode 5 even that has been removed. I'll leave it to others to explain whether the Apple dylib is compatible with real GCC.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=...:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

to prioritize apple's dylibs.